# liff redirect to liff.line.me 400 bad request

Tags: line, xliff

When a user performs certain actions within LIFF (Line Front-end Framework), they are redirected to liff.line.me and receive a 400 bad request error. What could potentially be the cause of this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YRL5.png)

I've tested this and everything appears to be normal. Only a few users have encountered this situation.